# How to make sure my map is never modified once set in my Builder pattern?

Tags: java, multithreading, dictionary, thread-safety, final

Below is my builder pattern which I am using in one of my projects and I wanted to make it thread safe in multithreading environment. Once the `ClientKey` is set, I don't want anyone to modify it again.

```
public final class ClientKey {

    private final long userId;
    private final int clientId;
    private final long timeout;
    private final boolean dataFlag;
    // how can I make sure that my parameterMap is never modified once set
    private final Map<String, String> parameterMap;

    private ClientKey(Builder builder) {
        this.userId = builder.userId;
        this.clientId = builder.clientId;
        this.remoteFlag = builder.remoteFlag;
        this.dataFlag = builder.dataFlag;
        this.parameterMap = builder.parameterMap;
        this.timeout = builder.timeout;
    }

    public static class Builder {
        protected final long userId;
        protected final int clientId;
        protected long timeout = 200L;
        protected boolean remoteFlag = false;
        protected boolean dataFlag = true;
        protected Map<String, String> parameterMap;

        public Builder(long userId, int clientId) {
            this.userId = userId;
            this.clientId = clientId;
        }

        public Builder parameterMap(Map<String, String> parameterMap) {
            this.parameterMap = parameterMap;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder remoteFlag(boolean remoteFlag) {
            this.remoteFlag = remoteFlag;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder dataFlag(boolean dataFlag) {
            this.dataFlag = dataFlag;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder addTimeout(long timeout) {
            this.timeout = timeout;
            return this;
        }

        public ClientKey build() {
            return new ClientKey(this);
        }
    }

    public long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public int getClientId() {
        return clientId;
    }

    public long getTimeout() {
        return timeout;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getParameterMap() {
        return parameterMap;
    }

    public boolean isDataFlag() {
        return dataFlag;
    }
}
```

In my above `ClientKey`, sometimes I will pass `parameterMap` while making ClientKey object but sometimes, it will be null. It is not always that we will set `parameterMap`. And below is the way I am iterating  `parameterMap` in my application code once ClientKey object is set and passed around in my application code:

```
final Map<String, String> parameterMap = clientKey.getParameterMap();
if (!MapUtils.isEmpty(parameterMap)) {
    Set<Entry<String, String>> params = parameterMap.entrySet();

    for (Entry<String, String> e : params) {
        url.append("&").append(e.getKey());
        url.append("=").append(e.getValue());
    }
}
```

Question is - How can I make sure that my parameterMap is never modified in between once it has been set. As you can see once I have build the ClientKey object, the parameterMap is only ever read and never modified. However it relies on the fact that no malicious or buggy client isn't trying to modify in the meantime so what's the best way to protect against that?

Comment: Only expose defensive deep copies of the map, if you expose anything at all.

Comment: `How can I make sure that my parameterMap is never modified` Plus one for comment by @Hovercraft Full Of Eels - an [Unmodifiable Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap%28java.util.Map%29) will throw an Exception if code attempts to modify

Comment: Do you want to prevent the map _contents_ modification after you have created a `ClientKey` or to prevent the builder from setting the map twice (by calling `Builder.parameterMap()` twice)?

Comment: @SergeyTachenov If they set tthe map twice, it will use always the second value they set right? Do I need  to worry about that?

Comment: @david, I don't know, you tell me that. Maybe it's exactly that what worries you, because the first value will be completely forgotten, and this is what you're trying to prevent? It is a bit unclear from your wording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such cases I recommend using Guava's [`ImmutableMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html). I also suggest avoiding `null` value for `parameterMap` field and use an empty `ImmutableMap` instead. For that you could also use its [`Builder`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html#builder()).

So your code fragment would become:

```
public class ClientKey {
   ...
   private final ImmutableMap<String, String> parameterMap;

   public ClientKey(Builder builder) {
       ...
       this.parameterMap = builder.parameterMap.build();
       ...
   }

   public static class Builder {
        ...
        protected ImmutableMap.Builder<String, String> parameterMap = ImmutableMap.builder();

        public Builder parameterMap(Map<String, String> parameterMap) {
            this.parameterMap.putAll(parameterMap);
            return this;
        }

        public Builder addParameter(String key, String value) {
            this.parameterMap.put(key, value);
            return this;
        }
     }
 }
```

Using immutable map will make it clear to the `ClientKey` users that it cannot be modified.

Comment: Thanks for the help. If I use like this `this.parameterMap = (builder.parameterMap == null) ? null : ImmutableMap.copyOf(builder.parameterMap);` in `ClientKey` constructor then is it ok? Or do I need to use the way you are suggesting me?

Comment: Is there any reason you are suggesting to avoid `null` for `parameterMap`? Just wanted to understand.

Comment: I strongly recommend reading the relevant section of [Guava documentation](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained) which provides rationale on avoiding `null` values where possible.

Comment: sure, tell me one more thing if I go this route and if they want to add more key values in the map then how will it looks like? Let's say I want to add 5 entries in the map, then how will I do it with this approach?

Comment: @david Do you want to add more entries to the map in the builder or in the `ClientKey` class?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your answer. I guess you don't want to be able to modify `ClientKey.parameterMap` as that was the requirement in your question. And it is impossible as we use `ImmutableMap` there (just try :)). So I guess you want to add those 5 entries in the `Builder.parameterMap` you could either just call `builder.parameterMap(<your-5-entries-in-another-map>` or invoke `builder.addParameter` for each of those entries.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to prevent *any* modifications to the map *contents* after a `ClientKey` instance have been created, you should use this in the constructor:

```
    if (builder.parameterMap == null) {
        this.parameterMap = null;
    } else {
        this.parameterMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(builder.parameterMap);
    }
```

If you want to allow modifications from the `ClientKey` code only, and not from outside, you should return an `unmodifiableMap()` in `getParameterMap()` instead, but then it wouldn't be completely thread-safe - you'd have to use a `ConcurrentMap` then.

Comment: I tried using this and it works fine when I am setting the `parameterMap` while making `ClientKey` object. But when I don't set `parameterMap` while making `ClientKey` object, then it gives me NPE. Any idea how we can fix that?

Comment: Can we also write like this? `this.parameterMap = (builder.parameterMap == null) ? null : Collections.unmodifiableMap(builder.parameterMap);` And this will be in `ClientKey` constructor? Right?

Comment: @david, yes, of course. It's a matter of style, and both styles have their merits. And of course it will be in the constructor, I mention that right before the code (and you can't assign a final variable anywhere else anyway).